# How to keep a check box "unchecked" in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to keep a check box "unchecked" in my custom module,
Any Idea on this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Could you explain it better?

Comment: I am replacing a field in Calendar module, Allday is the check box field, i am trying to replace it with another checkbox field and set it unchecked

Comment: either way i want to know what keeps that allday checkbox checked.

Comment: Then you should set `default=False` in the field declaration and don't show it in the form, or make it invisible.

Comment: If it has a compute function, check it, maybe you have to override it as well

Comment: ok @ChesuCR, Thank you very much for the suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that, you must set it as readonly, that way no user will be able to set it as True.

Comment: set it as readonly will prevent the user from making changes forvas, i have done that, but i want it unchecked

Comment: Ok, then, as @ChesuCR wrote, you should set its default parameter as False. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Just make this changes to field.boolean("string",default=False,readonly=False, ,required=False)

It will works, Thanks